# Firebase Cloud Messaging Log

Tags: google-chrome, web, firebase, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging

Is there a way I can check Firebase Cloud Messaging logs?

There's this [help documentation](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/2663268?hl=en), but it seems to be outdated. I tried it out with no luck and I'm out of $25.

I'm trying to send push notifications, while the request is accepted from the servers, the push notification just isn't sent to the browser.

I get the following http response when submitting the push notification from my server

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK [Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8, Date: Fri, 06 Jan 2017 02:06:05 GMT, Expires: Fri, 06 Jan 2017 02:06:05 GMT, Cache-Control: private, max-age=0, X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff, X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN, X-XSS-Protection: 1; mode=block, Server: GSE, Alt-Svc: quic=":443"; ma=2592000; v="35,34", Transfer-Encoding: chunked] [Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8,Content-Length: 119,Chunked: false]
```

But while the server accepts the input, nothing is pushed to the server.
The service worker is successfully registered in the browser, and when I select "push" option from the dev console in chrome notification is displayed successfully.

This is the code in my service worker.

```
importScripts('https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/3.5.2/firebase-app.js');
importScripts('https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/3.5.2/firebase-messaging.js');

firebase.initializeApp({
    'messagingSenderId': '384333585283'
});

const messaging = firebase.messaging();

messaging.setBackgroundMessageHandler(function(payload) {
    console.log('[chrome_sw.js] Received background message ', payload);
    // Customize notification here
    const notificationTitle = 'Background Message Title';
    const notificationOptions = {
        body: 'Background Message body.',
        icon: '/firebase-logo.png'
    };

    return self.registration.showNotification(notificationTitle,
        notificationOptions);
});

self.addEventListener('push', function(event) {
    console.log('[Service Worker] Push Received.');
    console.log('[Service Worker] Push had this data: '+event.data.text());

    const title = 'Push Codelab';
    const options = {
        body: 'Yay it works.',
        icon: 'images/icon.png',
        badge: 'images/badge.png'
    };

    event.waitUntil(self.registration.showNotification(title, options));
});
```

Comment: Hi. FCM Diagnostics only works for apps that have been published for Alpha Testing or later. You mentioned that the requests were *accepted from the servers*, do you mean that the requests towards FCM is successful? If yes, then it could possibly be an issue on your client side code. Do post the related code snippets.

Comment: @AL. I submitted the code and the response. By app, did you mean an android app? I'm basically trying to push notifications to the chrome browser.

Comment: Yep, Android App. That's about the details I know with regards to the FCM Diagnostics. Don't know much for Chrome Push notifications though. Sorry.

Comment: @AL. No worries. I think I'll start over again and see if that gets me anywhere!

Comment: I have put many console.log in my firebase serviceworker but I don't see the output!!!  Help!